# Different key type in a map

Tags: c++, boost, boost-any

for a particular requirement I want to have a map with keys in different type. Similar to boost:any. (I have an old  gcc version)

```
map<any_type,string> aMap;

//in runtime :
aMap[1] = "aaa";
aMap["myKey"] = "bbb";
```

is this something possible with the use boost ?

thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not willing to use boost variant, you can hack your own key type.

You could use a discriminated union, or go low-tech en simply use a pair of `std::string` and int:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/23b1acd6ca70907c)</kbd>**

```
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

struct Key : std::pair<int, std::string> {
    using base = std::pair<int, std::string>;
    Key(int i) : base(i, "") {}
    Key(char const* s) : base(0, s) {}
    Key(std::string const& s) : base(0, s) {}

    operator int() const         { return base::first; }
    operator std::string() const { return base::second; }
    friend bool operator< (Key const& a, Key const& b) { return std::tie(a.first, a.second) <  std::tie(b.first, b.second); }
    friend bool operator==(Key const& a, Key const& b) { return std::tie(a.first, a.second) == std::tie(b.first, b.second); }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Key const& k) {
        return os << "(" << k.first << ",'" << k.second << "')";
    }
};

using Map = std::map<Key, std::string>;

int main()
{
    Map m;

    m[1] = "aaa";
    m["myKey"] = "bbb";

    for (auto& pair : m)
        std::cout << pair.first << " -> " << pair.second << "\n";
}
```

Prints:

```
(0,'myKey') -> bbb
(1,'') -> aaa
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the clue. exploring discriminated union as a personal improvement.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use `boost::variant`:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6945a2b3f9d8760e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using Key = boost::variant<int, std::string>;
using Map = std::map<Key, std::string>;

int main()
{
    Map m;

    m[1] = "aaa";
    m["myKey"] = "bbb";
}
```

Key ordering/equation is automatically there. Note though that `"1"` and `1` are *different* keys in this approach.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. as stated in my question, I'm using an old compiler adn requirement is not to use boost.

Comment: The question was tagged [tag:boost]. The questing text says "is this something possible with the use boost ?'. Old gcc versions will work fine. Perhaps you can use an older version of boost as well

Comment: May be I should be more precise :). It's a legacy syste,, and there is no  way to change the build environment or dependencies.

Comment: I don't think that's relevant. Just decide whether the answer answers the question (it does) and whether you found it helpful. If you had another question, you will have to post one.