# Store multiple types as values in C++ dictionary?

Tags: python, c++

I want to write a C++ object that behaves almost equivalent to a Python dictionary. C++'s `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` accommodate some of the functionalities that Python dictionaries already have, yet lack one of the most important capabilities, namely, being able to add arbitrary objects and types. Even if it isn't possible, how close can you get to achieving the capabilities of Python's dictionary?

A few previous questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674009/c-equivalent-of-python-dictionaries) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1842941/translating-python-dictionary-to-c)) fail to handle the issue of adding multiple types to the dictionary.

For example, I want to be able to do something like this in C++:

```py
my_dict = {'first': 1,
           'second': "string",
           'third': 3.5,
           'fourth': my_object}
my_dict['fifth'] = list([1, 2, 3])
```

The best solutions that I can think would be like using `void` pointers to data which get reinterpreted, or perhaps some kind of run-time polymorphism with some type restrictions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ equivalent of Python dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674009/c-equivalent-of-python-dictionaries)

Comment: @CalebGoodman I don't really think so. The op is asking about inserting elements of arbitrary type.

Comment: It's sort of possible but the code wouldn't look pretty. You'd also need to think about how you type an element that's retrieved. Feels like an X-Y problem or at-least a just for fun task, but I could be wrong, have you got a use case?

Comment: Quite frankly, using heterogeneous types in Python containers, although *definitely possible*, is not something that I would consider one of the "most important capabilities". In fact, I would say that having heterogenous types in your containers is almost always bad design.

Comment: Related: [C++ std::map holding ANY type of value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24702235/364696) (covers values).

Comment: Also related: [Different key type in a map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43161938/364696). That indicates it's doable with boost, doing it without boost was (at least at time question was asked) more limited. No idea if C++17 additions (e.g. `std::variant`/`std::any`) help here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The best solutions that I can think would be like using **void pointers to data which get reinterpreted**, or perhaps some kind of run-time polymorphism with some type restrictions?

Many void pointers and many reinterpretation of pointers in modern C++ should be a signal of a bad design, in my opinion. I believe that polymorphism would be a way to go.

Also, if you have a fixed number of types you want to use, consider using C++17's [std::any](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) or [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) which is a more modern `union`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

typedef std::map<std::variant<int, std::string>, std::variant<int, std::string>> Dict;

int main(){
    Dict d;
    d["key"] = 1;
    d[5] = "woah";
    std::cout << std::get<int>(d["key"]) << std::endl; // prints 1

    // edit: print all the keys in d
    for(auto& k_v: d){
        std::visit(
            [](auto& value){std::cout << value << ' ';},
            k_v.first // k_v.second to print all values in d
        );
    }

}
```

The above example might be useful in some use-cases.

Also check out how json objects are implemented in any C++ json library. It might be helpful.

Edit: I added an example of `std::visit` that iterates over keys in our dictionary.

Comment: Also, _don't do this_. Prefer to always know the interface of the values you need to work with.

Comment: What do you mean with *don't do this*?
Using such multitype dicts isn't a good idea in the first place, so if *don't do this* is according to it, I agree.

Comment: Could you add a short example showing how to use `std::visit`? That's the preferred interface for `std::variant`, and it's often easier to use than calling `std::get`

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a similar solution for hard coding the parameters of my `python` experiments into `c++`. I found the `std'17 variant` module very useful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(){
    typedef std::map<std::variant<std::string, int>, std::variant<int, double, float, std::string>> Dict;

    std::vector<Dict> params = {
        {
            {"label", "Labs"},
            {"dir", "/media/sf_Data/"},
            {"num_frames", 4},
            {"scale_factor", 1.0},
            {5, "my number five"},
        }, // Dict 0
        {
            {"label", "Airplanes"},
            {"dir", "/media/m_result/"},
            {"num_frames", 5},
            {"scale_factor", 0.5},
            {5, "number five"},
        } // Dict 1
    };

    int idx = 1;
    std::string label   = std::get<std::string>(params[idx]["label"]);
    std::string folder  = std::get<std::string>(params[idx]["dir"]);
    int num_frames      = std::get<int>(params[idx]["num_frames"]);
    double scf          = std::get<double>(params[idx]["scale_factor"]);
    std::string nbstr   = std::get<std::string>(params[idx][5]);
    
    std::cout << label << std::endl;
    std::cout << folder << std::endl;
    std::cout << num_frames << std::endl;
    std::cout << scf << std::endl;
    std::cout << nbstr << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result:

```
Airplanes
/media/m_result/
5
0.5
number five
```