# Having trouble making a map with different types

Tags: c++

I want to make a map that has string keys that have string values and with the second data type being string keys with a list value.

I tried following the solutions mentioned under this thread: [Store multiple types as values in C++ dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56350891/store-multiple-types-as-values-in-c-dictionary) but I keep on getting these errors. Any help is appreciated, I've been at this for quite some time.

`'variant' is not a member of 'std'`
even though I have it included on top

`template argument 1 is invalid`
on the string syntax

`no operator "=" matches these operands`  on the equal signs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <variant>

typedef std::map<std::variant<std::string, std::list<std::string>>, std::variant<std::string, std::string>> Dict;

int main(){
    std::list<std::string> List1 {"Teamwork", "Hate"};
    Dict d;
    d["TIME"] = "8:15";
    d["TAGS"] = List1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a strange requirement to have. Looking at your `main` function... don't you want to simply use a struct or class instead?

Comment: @Thomas probably, I'm just trying to get this to work so I could copy paste it over to my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map<std::variant<std::string, std::list<std::string>>, std::variant<std::string, std::string>>`

Is a map with (`string` or `list` keys) and (`string` or `string`) of values. Having variant with duplicate types is allowed but unnecessary and it will complicate things.

You want
`std::map<std::string,std::variant<std::string, std::list<std::string>>>` i.e. map with `string` keys and (`string` or `list`) values.

This compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include <variant>
// Prefer using in C++ to typedef.
using Dict = std::map<std::string,std::variant<std::string, std::list<std::string>>>;

int main(){
    std::list<std::string> List1 {"Teamwork", "Hate"};
    Dict d;
    d["TIME"] = "8:15";
    d["TAGS"] = List1;

    return 0;
}
```

Variants are c++17, make sure you have it set if you are getting include errors.

Comment: This compiles online but I can't seem to get it to work on my machine

Comment: @Buddy What compiler are you using?

Comment: nevermind thanks for the help, I messed around and got it to finally use c++20. Now everything works dandy